# Apply Mann Whitney U test on multidimensional array and replace single values of variable of xarray data array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, dataset, python-xarray

I'm new to Python and need some help with xarray.
I have two 3 dimensional data arrays (rlon, rlat, time) for future and past climate. I want to compute the Mann-Whitney-U-test for each grid point to analyse significance of temperature change in future compared to past. I already got the Mann-Whitney-U-test work with selecting a time serie from one grid point of historical and future data each. Example:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import scipy.stats as sts

#selecting time period and grid point of past and future data

tp = fileHis['tas']
tf = fileFut['tas']
gridpoint_past=tp.sel(rlon=-6.375, rlat=1.375, time=slice('1999-01-01', '1999-01-31'))
gridpoint_future=tf.sel(rlon=-6.375, rlat=1.375, time=slice('2099-01-01', '2099-01-31'))

#mannwhintey-u-test

result=sts.mannwhitneyu(gridpoint_past, gridpoint_future, alternative='two-sided')
print('pvalue =',result[1])
```

Output:
`pvalue = 0.05922372345359562`

My problem now is that I need to do this for each grid point and each month and in the end I would like to have a data array with pvalues for each grid point and each month of a year.
I was thinking about looping through all rlat, rlon and months and run the Mann-Whitney-U-test for each, unless there is a better way to do.?
And how can I write the pvalues one by one into a new data array with the same rlat, rlon dimension?
I was trying this, but it does not work:
I created a data array `pvalue_mon`, which has the same rlat, rlon as `tp` and `tf` and has 12 months as time steps.

```
pvalue_mon.sel(rlon=-6.375, rlat=1.375, time=th.time.dt.month.isin([1])) = result[1] 
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

or this:

```
pvalue_mon.sel(rlon=-6.375, rlat=1.375, time=pvalue_mon.time.dt.month.isin([1])).update(result[1])
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

How can I replace a single value of an existing variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the .sel() function, try using .loc[ ] as described here:
http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html#assigning-values-with-indexing